# Pascal's Triangle with Recursion

Tags: python, recursion, pascals-triangle

I need help generating a code that will print Pascal's triangle using recursion.

So far what I've done prints the output "[[1], [1, 1], [1, 2, 1], [1, 3, 3, 1], [1, 4, 6, 4, 1],", etc.

I need my results to print like

1

1 1

1 2 1

1 3 3 1

Each row being a new line of code. Is there any way to split the list so that it prints in that way, or do I need to start over?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please post a [mcve] that illustrates what you've done so far and where you're stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go like this:

```
a = [[1], [1, 1], [1, 2, 1], [1, 3, 3, 1], [1, 4, 6, 4, 1]]

for i in a:
    print(" ".join(map(str,i)))
    print() # if you want empty line between the rows.
```

Prettier like this: (indenting the rows)

```
for i,l in enumerate(a):
    print((len(a)-i)*" " +" ".join(map(str,l)))
```